# Reached end of code While Parsinng

Tags: parsing

I've come across an error saying i've reached the end of the file while parsing. I have an idea as to what to do, but am unsure as to where the missing Bracket should go. Please Help!

```
package fahrenheit;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Fahrenheit {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        FahrenheitPanel panel = new FahrenheitPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class FahrenheitPanel extends JPanel {
      private JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel, resultLabel;
      private JTextField fahrenheit;


        public FahrenheitPanel() {
            inputLabel = new JLabel ("Enter Fahrenheit Temperature:");
            outputLabel = new JLabel ("Temperature in Celsius");
            resultLabel = new JLabel ("---");

            fahrenheit = new JTextField (5);
            fahrenheit.addActionListener (new TempListener());

            add (inputLabel);
            add (fahrenheit);
            add (outputLabel);
            add (resultLabel);

            setPreferredSize (new Dimension (300, 75));
            setBackground (Color.yellow);

        }

            private class TempListener implements ActionListener
            {
              public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
              {
                  int fahrenheitTemp, celsiusTemp;

                  String text = fahrenheit.getText();

                  fahrenheitTemp = Integer.parseInt (text);
                  celsiusTemp = (fahrenheitTemp-32) * 5/9;

                  resultLabel.setText (Integer.toString (celsiusTemp));
              }
            }
    }
```

I am Really unsure as to where i need to place the bracket. PLEASE if someone could help that would be FANTASTIC!

Comment: You are missing a closing brace for the class. Use an editor (Eclipse, Netbeans and many other out there) which would give you the error.

Comment: which code editor do you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead using

   ```
   Integer.toString(...)
   ```

   use

   ```
   String.valueOf(...)
   ```
2. You cannot reference non-static classes in a static class. Make the FahrenheitPanel class static. And the posted code is missing a parenthesis at the very end.